# How can I format an address so that it will turn into an apple maps link

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I am working for a company that requires calendar events be sent to the iPhones of field service engineers.

Included in the Event is the customer address.

```
123 Fake St
Fakeville Town 
NSW 2500 AUSTRALIA
```

is there a way to print this address into the event so that an iphone can click on the address and open it in maps.

The following have been tested:
(only the italicized section of the address becomes the link, and will always default to 123 fake street - somewhere in America.)

> *123 Fake St*, Fakefille
>
> *123 Fake St* Fakefille

any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this documentation :
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Your URL could look something like this :
`http://maps.apple.com/?address=123,Fake,St,Fakefille+Town,AUSTRALIA`

Clicking this link will open the maps app.